# How to run 5 php processes, which uses different eth interfaces?

Tags: centos, ethernet, php-cli

I'm using cron to run everyday script, which has to run 5 php-cli processes. I need them to use separate interfaces.

I have 5 devices, eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3, eth4.

How can I call php to make sure it uses only one of them?

It's running on Centos 6.6

Comment: What do you mean by using interface? What is your process/script doing?

Comment: My script downloads data using curl (called as class from PHP, not as command). When I run this script, it always uses eth0 to connect.
I need something like:
`php script.php --interface=eth0 && php script.php --interface=eth1` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a related post from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425651/471547).

You need to use function call like the following to set interface name or IP address.

```
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use a different interface in each case?  Unless you are benchmarking the interfaces and for some reason want to do that in php, then there is probably a better solution.

libcurl does implement this sort of functionality, but I'm not sure about php's binding for it.  If it's not there, you could just use the `curl` command directly via a shell call.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

```
   --interface <name>
          Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can  enter
          interface  name,  IP address or host name. An example could look
          like:

           curl --interface eth0:1 http://www.netscape.com/
```

(Wow.  netscape.com, eh?  Noone's gone over that man page in a while).